# Paypal Multiple Items with Prices Drop Down Form?

Tags: php, paypal

Hey Guys so im trying to code a section of a site using Paypal all was going fine until I needed to add the option if the customer wishes to purchase an extra item and what colour they would like it. I can get the colour chosen across to Paypal however I cant seem to add the extra price of £12.00 on to the bill, I have the option for advance shipping that works fine just not sure where im going wrong?

```
 <form target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<!-- Replace "business" value with your PayPal Email Address or your Merchant Account ID -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email@mybiz.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Personal Built Board">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="45.00">
<!-- Replace value with the web page you want the customer to return to after a successful transaction -->
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/ThankYou.html">
<!-- Replace value with the web page you want the customer to return to after item cancellation -->
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.yourwebsite.com/Cancel.html">
<!-- Note: shipping override variable is used with this example -->
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0.00">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHosted">

<div class="build1">Select Board:&#160;&#160;
<input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Board">
<select name="os1">
<option value="BLACK" selected>BLACK</option>
<option value="LIGHT BLUE">LIGHT BLUE</option>
<option value="DARK BLUE">DARK BLUE</option>
<option value="PINK">PINK</option>
<option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
<option value="RED">RED</option>
<option value="PURPLE">PURPLE</option>
<option value="ORANGE">ORANGE</option>
<option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
<option value="WHITE">WHITE</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="build2">Front Wheels:&#160;&#160;
<input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Wheels">
<select name="os2">
<option value="BLUE" selected>BLUE</option>
<option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
<option value="PINK">PINK</option>
<option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
<option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
<option value="WHITE">WHITE</option>
<option value="ORANGE">ORANGE</option>
<option value="RED">RED</option>
<option value="PURPLE">PURPLE</option>
<option value="PURPLE TRANS">PURPLE TRANS</option>
<option value="CLEAR BLACK">CLEAR BLACK</option>
<option value="CLEAR WHITE">CLEAR WHITE</option>
</select></div>

<div class="build4">Select Truck:&#160;&#160;
<input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Truck">
<select name="os3">
<option value="ALUMINUM" selected>ALUMINUM</option>
<option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
<option value="WHITE">WHITE</option>
</select></div>

<div class="build3">Back Wheels:&#160;&#160;
<input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Wheels">
<select name="os2">
<option value="BLUE" selected>BLUE</option>
<option value="BLACK">BLACK</option>
<option value="PINK">PINK</option>
<option value="GREEN">GREEN</option>
<option value="YELLOW">YELLOW</option>
<option value="WHITE">WHITE</option>
<option value="ORANGE">ORANGE</option>
<option value="RED">RED</option>
<option value="PURPLE">PURPLE</option>
<option value="PURPLE TRANS">PURPLE TRANS</option>
<option value="CLEAR BLACK">CLEAR BLACK</option>
<option value="CLEAR WHITE">CLEAR WHITE</option>
</select></div>

<div class="build5">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Extra Wheels?&#160;&#160;
    <input type="hidden" name="on4" value="Extra Wheels">
    <select name="os4">
      <option value="BLUE" selected>BLUE</option>
      <option value="MORE COLOURS TO BE ADDED">MORE</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="BLUE">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="12.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="build5">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>Next Day Delivery?&#160;&#160;
    <select name="shipping" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
      <option selected value="0.00">NO</option>
      <option value="4.99">YES</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </p>
</div>

<div class="get-download">
                <p>&nbsp;  </p>
                <p>
                  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
                  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></p>
                  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not 100%, but I think PayPal only allows one select form that has prices within it, this must be os0.

So you will need to move any options that have prices to be os0, this will then relate to option_amount0 and option_select0.

```
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Extra Wheels">
<select name="os0">
  <option value="BLUE" selected>BLUE</option>
  <option value="MORE COLOURS TO BE ADDED">MORE</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="BLUE">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="12.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">
```